# How do I rename a category in Steam?

Tags: steam

In Steam you can organise the games in your library by creating categories and adding the games to them:

[image: Game categories link]

However, there appears to be no option to rename these. How can I do this?

Comment: The "No." category gave me a chuckle :-)

Comment: Your categories are similar to mine :) Except I have to break down each category even further since I have too many games.

Comment: @6005 They aren't my categories I my have borrowed the image :P

Comment: I have nearly 600 games in my steam library and I'm too lazy to sort them all out straight away so I'm doing them a bit at a time.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

One way you can do this is to move all the games to a newly created category and delete the old one (A category is deleted when no games are inside of it). You can do this by:

1. Select all the games in the category:

   - Control click on all the ones you want
   - Shift click the top and the bottom one
2. Right click on the selected games
3. From the list select "Set Categories..."
4. In the new window create the new category
5. Add the games to the new category and remove them from the old one

Another way to do this is to change the [settings file](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3036214). Before altering this file make sure to close and exit steam. The file is located where steam is installed, in my case it is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam
```

From this root it is located at:

```
root\userdata\<userid>\7\remote\sharedconfig.vdf
```

Where `<userid>` corresponds to the users library you want to update. Open this file in notepad, or better yet notepad++. You then need to find and replace all examples of the category surrounded by quotes.

For example, if I wanted to rename the category `Want to play` to `Meh` I'd find on `"Want to play"` and replace with `"Meh"`.

Once you've made all the relevant changes to the file, save it and open steam again.

Comment: This is true, there is no way to rename the category. Categories simply cease to exist once there are no more games in them, so creating a new one is really your only route.

Comment: And nice..... Answering your own question like that. Its almost as if you had the answer the whole time....

Comment: @Beninja2 Side note: Self answering is actually encouraged to help spread information :)

Comment: Is multi-selecting games a new feature? I feel like I've tried that before with no success (but I could have been doing it wrong as well).

Comment: @BrianJ No idea I only tried it today haha

Comment: @Beninja2: Not only is self-answering acceptable, it's actually encouraged.  There's even [an achievement for it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/14/self-learner)!

Answer (score 16):

If like me you've got way too many Steam games to manage through their crap interface, [Depressurizer](https://github.com/Theo47/depressurizer) is a pretty nifty tool to manage your Steam library.

It will let you rename categories albeit you asked how to do that from Steam and @TheLethalCoder already answered that's not directly possible.

Comment: 'crap' seems a bit harsh. I think 'feature deprived' is probably more apt.

Comment: @TimmyJim Recommending an alternative technology to accomplish a task is definitely worthy of an answer.

Comment: This is the best answer. Honestly, Steam's UI for categories is pretty awful. Depressurizer alleviates a lot of that pain.