# How do I organise my games in Steam?

Tags: steam

In my steam library my games are all under the Games tab with seemingly no way to organise them. I can sort them by clicking the headers but that appears to be it.

How can I organise my games?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can firstly move games you like playing often into your "Favorites". You do this by:

1. Navigating to the game in your library (note you can select multiple at a time)
2. Right click it
3. In the context menu that opens select "Add to Favorites"

If you're looking for more advanced organisation you can add your games into categories. You do this by:

1. Navigating to the game in your library (note you can select multiple at a time)
2. Right click it
3. In the context menu that opens select "Set Categories..."
4. In the new window that pops up, if the category doesn't exist, add it
5. Select the category to add the game to
6. Click "OK"

You can even hide games from being shown in the library, to do this:

1. Navigating to the game in your library (note you can select multiple at a time)

   2. Right click it
   3. In the context menu that opens select "Set Categories..."
   4. In the new window that pops up, check "Hide this game in my library"
   5. Click "OK"

Comment: Is there a way to do this automatically? Like using tags other people have already set/important categories?

Comment: @S.Wessels Not that I am aware of, if you look at my answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/307283/how-do-i-rename-a-category-in-steam) you will find the file this information is stored in. The categories are added per game, not games to categories so I'd say not.

Comment: On the up side, this means you can create categories that make sense *to you* in order to organize your games however *you* please.  Also worth noting: there is an option to hide games if, for example, you have a bunch of "free promo" downloads that you never asked for.  (I had a bunch of Counterstrike stuff that I think came bundled with Half-Life 2, for example.)

Comment: @Steve-O True will edit that into the answer. The only problem with it to me is that categories are added to games, not the other way around, meaning it is awkward when altering the file. Not that Steam wants you to do that obviously

Comment: @S.Wessels: Yes, see Phlarx's answer

Comment: @Steve-O: You can remove free-to-play games from your library from [this page](https://store.steampowered.com/account/licenses/) _(it's also [possible](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30322) to remove non-free games)_

Answer (score 5):

[Depressurizer](https://github.com/rallion/depressurizer/releases) is a third-party tool designed to make categorization easier, and it has some automatic categorization features as well.

I've only used it once, but I have no complaints.

(Just make sure Steam is not running when you use the tool, as described in their usage guide.)